# How do we formalize the derivation of the ideal gas law from Boyle's Law, Charles's Law, and Avogadro's Law?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, education

Given:

- $V \propto 1/P$
- $V \propto T$
- $V \propto n$

Prove that:

$V \propto \frac{nT}{P}$

Here is the intuitive argument I have: We can see that

1. $V = \langle \text{mystery meat} \rangle  1/P$
2. $V = \langle \text{mystery meat} \rangle  T$, and
3. $V = \langle \text{mystery meat} \rangle  n$

but it's possible to interpret it so that the mystery meat in (1) is actually equal to $nT$, and the mystery meat in (2) is equal to $\frac{n}{P}$, and the mystery meat in (3) is equal to $\frac{T}{P}$ and so it ends up looking like the [blind men touching the elephant.](https://www.agileland.com/done/)

...But I don't know how to make this intuitive argument formal. How would this be turned into a formal proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my humble opinion, I think that we must start with historical data

- In year $1662$, Boyle *experimentally* observed that, at constant temperature, the product $PV$ is *almost* a constant
- In year $1787$, Charles *experimentally* observed that, at constant pressure, the change of volume is proportional to the change of temperature.
- In year $1834$, Clapeyron combined the two facts and proposed $PV=kT$ and, at that time, $k$ was supposed to be component dependent before becoming the universal $R$.
- Volume is an extensive property.

These are *experimental* facts which have been turned into the first equation of state ($PV=RT$ is **not** a law).

It is from here that all theoretical work started.

If you are concerned by the next steps, I could add (even a lot !).

**Edit**

Very early, thermodynamicists point ted out that this was not good since $PV=RT$

- first aof all, traduces only repulsion between molecules (and, if there is repulsion, there is attration somewhere !)
- would lead to a zero volume at constant $T$ and infinite $P$ which is not possible.

Already, in year $1865$, Dupré introduced the concept of the covolume (the limit of volume at infinite  pressure and constant temperature) and proposed o rewrite
$$P(V-b_T)=RT$$

Back to *experimantal*, in these years, in order to have nice plots, physicists used to plot pressure as polynomials of the reciprocal of volume
$$P=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{a_n(T)}{V^n}$$ which was already called as *virial expansion*.

Back to physics, the jey year is $1873$ when Van der Waals combined all of the above and proposed
$$\large\color{blue}{P=\frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac a{V^2}}$$ which, expanded as a series, gives
$$P=\frac {R T}V-\frac{a-b R T}{V^2}+RT \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{b^{n-1}}{V^n}$$ which, written as
$$P=\frac {R T}V+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{A_n(T)}{V^n}$$ is the standard form of the *virial equation of state*.

Van der Waals equation of state is so simple that all modern developments of cubic equations of state started from here.

*To be continued if you wish.*

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. And yes, I am concerned by the next steps.

Comment: Please excuse me, but this is flying waay over my head. I thought that the simple change of the = symbol to the $\propto$ symbol would result in a simple argument. I didn't expect to become embroiled in this type of deep magic in the process of combining three proportional relationships. I came up with an intuitive argument that sounds correct, and I was hoping that perhaps there would be a simple geometric argument or algebraic technique that would make that argument formal.